# Add memberOf attribute to all users in OpenLDAP on OS X Lion Server Open Directory

Tags: mac-osx, openldap, opendirectory

Our school's website has the ability to pull user authentication from a LDAP source. They "support" and LDAP. Unfortunately, to pull group membership you must have a memberOf attribute in each users' record. OS X Lion Server does not store users group membership in their record by default.

I've read about OpenLDAP's memberOf overlay, and I am hoping that will work. But I don't know how to set it up, I've read the comment on [How do I configure Reverse Group Membership Maintenance on an openldap server? (memberOf)](https://serverfault.com/questions/73213/how-do-i-configure-reverse-group-membership-maintenance-on-an-openldap-server) but I'm not comfortable importing the LDIF until I know better what it does and if I have to import an ldif for each user. Also, I believe Open Directory uses posixGroups not a groupOfNames.

Questions:
Is it possible to enable the memberOf attribute in Apple's OS X Open Directory implementation of OpenLDAP?
If I enable it will it dynamically update the memberOf attribute when I add users to groups with Workgroup Manager?
How do I enable the memberOf attribute?